# Javascript validation function not being executed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having to dip my toe back in the EE and javascript world after many years. What am I doing wrong here... a simple form being submitted, with a JS block to validate during the `onsubmit` event of the submit button. The `alert("Here")` message box does not appear when I submit the form, and the form gets submitted successfully, i.e. `HelloForm` gets displayed, with blank values, so I'm led to believe that `validate()` is not being called. I've tried this in both the Eclipse internal web browser as well as Chrome and see the same thing both times. I'm assuming that I don't need to explicitly activate javascript in either browser, as it would be on by default.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validate()
{
    alert("Here");
    var x = document.forms["inputForm"].["first_name"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="inputForm" action="HelloForm" method="GET" onsubmit="return validate()">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
<br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit The Form"  />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try to call this validate(); function on Button Click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line will throw a syntax error:

```
document.forms["inputForm"].["first_name"].value
                          ^^^
```

The statement is wrong, should be without dot between braces:

```
document.forms["inputForm"]["first_name"].value
//or
document.forms.inputForm.first_name.value
```

**[Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Html5 Validations.

```
<form name="inputForm" action="HelloForm" method="GET" >
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" required />
<br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" required />
<input type="submit" value="Submit The Form"  />
</form>
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5vka1z6m/)**